# a:hover with css sprites z-index problem

Tags: css

I have worked with CSS Sprites many times before and have never come across this problem.

There is no change happening on hover and the link itself is not being recognized as link (ie on hover the cursor doesn't change and is not clickable at all)

I have a feeling that the reason they are not working is because of the z-index property being used on the parent element.

I have tried to solve this by setting the z-index of relevant a class  to higher z-index than that of the containing (parent) element but the a:hover background position change is still not visible....

Any ideas as to how I can go about solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `z-index` declaration of `#slideshowContainer`.
2. The hover works only half of the time, probably because the jQuery transition plugin you use plays with opacity and z-index. You may want to play with it, or replace it with something else.

Comment: thx battal ....but removing the z-index on #slideshowContainer will present me with further problems I was using it as workaround for internet explorer with the fade in transitions.....ie fades in the background along with the images which was not the effect i wanted....i guess like you said might have to play with jquery plugin itself...but was hoping there was a css only work around